# Get Custom Tag Name of JSP TLIB at doStartTag function

Tags: java, jsp, tags, taglib, custom-tag

I need to get the name of requester tag at doStartTag function
I have this Custom tag in .tld

```
<tag>
    <name>Resource</name>
    <tag-class>Mirnint.Interface.Tag.MNIT_Resources</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>Style</name>
        <required>false</required>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>JavaScript</name>
        <required>false</required>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

and in JSP :-

```
<%@ taglib uri="/webapp/Min" prefix="Min"%>
<html>
<head>
    <Min:Resource/>
</head>
```

and java class is :-

```
@Override
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
//Here i need to print the name of caller tag in this example it should be ("Resource")...
System.out.println(**The Name of Tag**);
}
```

Thou output Should be

```
Resource
```

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a getter/setter corresponding to name; then your code would be like:

```
public class Hello extends TagSupport {
    private String name=null;
    /**
      * Getter/Setter for the attribute name as defined in the tld file 
      * for this tag
      */
public void setName(String value){
    name = value;
}

    public String getName(){
          return(name);
       }
/**
* doStartTag is called by the JSP container when the tag is encountered
*/
    public int doStartTag() {
    System.out.println(name);
    }
```

Comment: What i need is the Name of TAG not a value of attribute "name"...

    <tag><name>Tag Name</name></tag>

Comment: What is the output of this program, could you please post it here?